# CUDA-OpenGL interoperability: minimum compute capability

Tags: cuda

Is there any minimum compute capability to use CUDA-OpenGL interoperability? I did not find any information about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works all the way back to CUDA compute 1.0.  I've been using [ArrayFire's Graphics Library](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/page_gfx.htm) with some really old cards (GT8400), as well as with the latest Kepler's (GTX690), which is the only way I know how it works across the wide range of cards.